# Problems mounting .iso bigger than 4.3 gb on saucy

Tags: 13.10, mount, iso

I upgraded to saucy a couple days ago on my Asus UX32VD-R4002H and I tried to mount various game isos. For some reason, it is impossible to mount images if they are as big as or bigger than 4.3 gb. Regardless of the method I tried, I always get an Input/Output error stating that it is not possible to open the image..and I tried a lot:

using command line (sudo) with:

- mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/Downloads/awesomegame.iso /media/1
- fuseiso awesomegame.iso /media/1
- converting the .iso with iat to ensure that they are iso9660 (although Im sure that all of them are)

tools i tried:

- opening/compress the isos with file-roller/7zip ->error
- acetoneiso
- gmountiso
- CDEmu
- iso master
- furius iso mount

I'm quite desperate right now, but I can imagine that it is just a simple configuration fault by myself, because all images work perfectly in Win7 with daemon tools. I haven't tried any of the images previously on another Ubuntu version.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance and best regards,

Fabian

//EDIT: Even when trying to copy the .iso to my external hdd or via network to another notebook, I ll get the I/O-Error...

Comment: Copying to another file system will be a different problem. Check if those are formatted to be FAT32 or something similar. It should work on NTFS partitions.

Comment: Show the exact error you get when you try to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount it with UDF instead:

```
sudo mount -t udf -o loop /home/Downloads/awesomegame.iso /media/1
```

Comment: You don't need udftools unless you plan on creating a udf image.